# XAMLでの複数の名前空間の割り当てをまとめたい

Tags: wpf, xaml

WPFアプリケーションでXAMLを書くとき、そこで必要とする他の名前空間を読み込むために[名前空間宣言](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms747086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)を書きます。
現在作っているアプリケーションでは、たくさんの自作のユーザーコントロールがあり、名前空間も細分化して管理しているのですが、それらを使うにあたって、いちいち個別のプレフィクスを付けるのが煩雑です。
ひとつのプレフィクスに複数の名前空間を割り当てたり（できないっぽいですが）、あるいはプレフィクスを使用せずに複数の名前空間にあるクラスを直接利用したりする方法はありますか？
それともやはり、愚直に個別のプレフィクスを割り当てていくしか無いのでしょうか？

環境はVS2013/.NET4.5.1(C#)/です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDNに記載のあるXmlnsDefinitionAttributeは複数の名前空間に同じURIを割り当てられます。
ただしプリフィクスを定義するXAMLと同一アセンブリには効果がないので、コントロールは別プロジェクトに分割する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。XmlnsDefinitionAttributeで綺麗にまとめることができました。